# How to prevent django from appending the url everytime?

Tags: python, html, django, url

I created two html file (home.html, admin.html). Both are linked to each other. Django, first opens up the `home.html`, with the url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/home` and as soon as a particular link is clicked, it is supposed to open the `admin.html`. Similarly, when a particular linked in `admin.html` is clicked, it opens up `home.html`.

But, the url keeps on extending
eg.

`127.0.0.1:8000/home -> 127.0.0.1:8000/home/admin -> 127.0.0.1:8000/home/admin/home`

and so on.....

How to stop django from constantly appending the url.

- `127.0.0.1:8000/home` should open `home.html`
- `127.0.0.1:8000/home/admin` should open `admin.html`

Comment: It's not Django, it's browser. Use slash in front of URLs where needed, e.g. `/home` instead of `home`. The latter is relative while the former is absolute.

Comment: What is the `href` you're adding to your anchor tags and what does your `urls.py` look like?

Comment: please give me `urls.py` and `views.py`. you set a wrong address for your link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have something like `<a href="admin/">` in your template. This tells to the browser "go to the subdirectory admin please", while what you want is "go to the URL /admin from the root of my website".

What you need is to use the `{% url %}` templatetag, which will prevent those sort of mistakes:

```
<a href="{% url 'my_admin_view' %}">Admin link</a>
```